# Delete Rows in SQL Table Based on Difference Between Values in Another Table

Tags: sql-server, date, time, sql-server-2014, sql-delete

I have one table (let's call it `dbo.temp`) that has minute by minute record of temperature from different sensors:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
| SENSOR_ID |   DATE     |   TIME   | TEMP |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:05:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:06:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:07:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:08:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:09:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:10:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:11:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:12:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:13:00 | 21.3 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:14:00 | 21.4 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:15:00 | 21.4 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:16:00 | 21.4 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:17:00 | 21.5 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:18:00 | 21.3 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:19:00 | 21.3 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:20:00 | 21.3 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:21:00 | 21.4 |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
```

And a second (dbo.datetime) contains date and time values.

```
+-------------+-----------+----------+
|    DATE     | TIME_A    | TIME_B  |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 2017-01-10  | 10:13:00  | 10:18:00 |
| 2017-01-11  | 09:18:00  | 10:28:00 |
| 2017-01-12  | 10:45:00  | 10:59:00 |
+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

I want to delete rows in `dbo.temp` where the time is between the two given in `dbo.datetime` on any given date. `SENSOR_ID` is not important as all data between `TIME_A` and `TIME_B` needs to be deleted.

For example I want dbo.temp to become this after the deletion between `TIME_A` and `TIME_B` on `2017-01-10`:

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
| SENSOR_ID |   DATE     |   TIME   | TEMP |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:05:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:06:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:07:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:08:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:09:00 | 21.1 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:10:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:11:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:12:00 | 21.2 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:19:00 | 21.3 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:20:00 | 21.3 |
|    106971 | 2017-01-10 | 10:21:00 | 21.4 |
+-----------+------------+----------+------+
```

How do I do this? `dbo.datetime` has daily `TIME_A` and `TIME_B` values for ~14 months, so don't want to manually `delete from dbo.temp where date = 'X' and time between 'Y' and 'Z'` each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if I understand you question, but you can try this query

```
DELETE t
FROM dbo.temp t
JOIN dbo.datetime d ON d.Date = t.Date
WHERE t.Time BETWEEN d.Time_A AND Time_B
```